# Compare sums of two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with a column named no_id, I want to test that the values in both columns on the tables are the same.

So I´m trying to sum the values of both columns and compare the result.

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN SUM (cast(a.no_id as bigint)) = SUM(cast(b.no_id as bigint)) THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
END as no_id
FROM table_a as a
    ,table_b as b
```

The result of the query is NO, but when I select each sum:

```
SELECT
    SUM (cast(a.no_id as bigint)),
    SUM(cast(b.no_id as bigint))
FROM table_a as a
    ,table_b as b
```

I got two nulls, one in each column. Instead of the sums of the columns.

I have to do this with other twenty columns of both tables.

no_id is a varchar(16) in both tables.

------UPDATE------

no_id only contains numeric strings,
I did the next query to ensure that null would be treated as 0:

```
    SELECT
    SUM(cast(ISNULL(a.no_id,0) as bigint)),
SUM(cast(ISNULL(b.no_id,0) as bigint))
    FROM table_a as a
    ,table_b as b
```

But I keep getting the same result.

If I select the result from just one table, it works, I get the result of the sum:

```
    SELECT
    SUM(cast(ISNULL(a.no_id,0) as bigint))
    FROM table_a as a
```

Then, why it doesn't work with both tables?

Comment: no_id is a varchar(16), how could you just cast and add? Are you sure no_id contains only numeric strings?

Comment: no_id is the same in both table? Can they join together by no_id?

Comment: @IndoKnight if `no_id` didn't contain a numeric string, the cast, and therefore query, would fail.

Comment: @IanNelson `Null values are ignored.` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

Comment: @Dave Zych Yes, I know. I'm trying to know if that is what intended.

Comment: Just checking - are there any rows in the tables?! An absence of any data would lead to a NULL result.

Comment: @David Acero no_id column must atleast have one NULL values, so the casting leads to NULL.

Comment: I can't prove it yet but I'm 99% sure this has to do with your select syntax. Doing the old style `SELECT ... FROM TableA, TableB` performs a join which is probably the problem.

Comment: 1) Don't use the comma(`,`) operator in the FROM clause, it's been obsolete for over twenty years, use the `JOIN` keyword syntax instead.  Because if you did you would know that 2) You are CROSS JOIN-ing your tables which is very bad and wrong 99% of the time.  You need to use column subqueries instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments:

1. Don't use the comma(`,`) operator in the FROM clause, it's been obsolete for over twenty years, use the JOIN keyword syntax instead. Because if you did you would know that ...
2. You are [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join)-ing your tables which is very bad and logically wrong 99% of the time. You need to use column subqueries instead.

Like this:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT SUM(cast(no_id as bigint)) FROM table_a)
       = (SELECT SUM(cast(no_id as bigint)) FROM table_b)  THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
END as no_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't say how `table_a` and `table_b` are related, so *every* row in `table_a` is paired with *every* row in `table_b` if either table has even one null value, then the total sum will be null.

If you just want the SUMS in both tables to match, then I;m not sure SUM is the best indicator.  If table A had the values 1 and 4, and table b had 2 and 3, then the SUM would match but obviously the values are different.